# Retrieve values of attributes from XML using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I am using XDocument.Parse method to load following XML :

```
<AuditMessage>

    <Event Action="Read" DateTime="2013/26/7" EventID="100"/>
    <User Role="Admin" UserID="12123"/User>
    <SourceIdentification SourceID="TeamLondon" SourceType="3"/>
    <Network AccessPointID="143.176.8.32" AccessPointTypeCode="1" />
    <Network AccessPointID="143.176.8.32" AccessPointTypeCode="`2" />
    <Participant ParticipantID="0001" ParticipantType ="2"/>
    <Participant ParticipantID="0002" ParticipantType ="3"/>
    <Participant ParticipantID="0003" ParticipantType ="3" ParticipantName = "Housh Mangrove"/>

</AuditMessage>
```

I need to retrieve the values of following attributes in the above XML.

```
-DateTime    
-Role    
-AccessPointID    
-ParticipantID    
-ParticipantName
```

I have used `sourceXML.Root.Element(nodeName).Attribute(attributeToMatch).Value` to read a single attribute. I am failing to understand how can I iterate the same thing over different nodes, provided some nodes might be missing.
Please notice :

1. `<Network>` and `<Participant>` nodes are repeating.
2. `ParticipantName` attribute exists only in one Instance of
3. Lastly, any node could be missing in different XMLs provided as Input. Therefore I need to write code in such a way that if a node is missing, the application doesn't throw OBJECT REFERENCE NOT FOUND Exception

Comment: this is pretty simple to do, did you make an attempt?

Comment: Yes I did, I can read a single attribute by using sourceXML.Root.Element(nodeName).Attribute(attributeToMatch).Value;
I was wondering if there is a simpler method as This will lead repetitive code

Comment: Check [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=xDocument+node+c%23)

Comment: Could you provide the output you would expect for the example you've given?

Comment: Well as of now, a comma separated string will do the job

Comment: @Murali I have been googling the whole day, I would appreciate if you could provide more specific link, as I have mentioned that reading attributes is not the problem, rather I want to devise a solution so that I can read them without a flaw provided variety in INPUT XMLs. Thanks

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase - could you provide the exact output you'd expect in your example, with some explanation if you believe anything could be unclear?

For example: as you've mentioned yourself - there are several `<Participant>` elements. Which should be chosen to obtain `ParticipantID`?

Comment: Okay, I am looking to extract the information as follow :-

2013/26/7, Admin, 143.176.8.32, 0001, 0002, 0003, HoushMangrove

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick attempt, you can figure out the ones I didn't add in:

```
public static void Main()
{
    GetAtts(xml);
}

public static Atts GetAtts(string xml)
{
    Atts atts = new Atts();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    if (doc.Root.Element("Event") != null)
        atts.datetime = doc.Root.Element("Event").Attribute("DateTime").Value;

    //...

    foreach (XElement ele in doc.Descendants("Network"))
        atts.accesspointid.Add(ele.Attribute("AccessPointID").Value);


    return atts;
}

public class Atts
{
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }

    private List<string>_accesspointid = new List<string>();
    public List<string> accesspointid { get { return _accesspointid; } set { _accesspointid = value; } }

    public List<string> _participantid = new List<string>();
    public List<string> participantid { get { return _participantid; } set { _participantid = value; } }

    public string participantname { get; set; }
}
```

you'll have an object you can handle more easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) method to get an enumeration of nodes of a given name.

You can then test if the enumeration returned any results and look for the appropriate attributes in them.

Something like this, if you want it as CSV:

```
var data = new List<string>();

var events = doc.Root.Elements("Event");

if (events.Any())
{
    foreach (var evt in events)
    {
        data.Add(evt.Attribute("DateTime").Value);
    }
}

var participants = doc.Root.Elements("Participant");

if (participants.Any())
{
    foreach (var participant in participants)
    {
        data.Add(participant.Attribute("ParticipantID").Value);
    }
}

var csv = string.Join(", ", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution - hopefully you can take it from here:

```
var participantID = String.Join(", ",
                                xdoc.Root.Elements("Participant")
                                         .Select(e => e.Attribute("ParticipantID"))
                                         .Where(a => a != null)
                                         .Select(a => a.Value)
                                         .Distinct());
```